# Opengl: How do I specify a directional vector for lighting in opengl?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, lighting

This doesn't make sense to me at all, but anyways, lets say we have this:

```
Glfloat dir[] = { 0.0, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, dir);
```

Guess what? The light rays point UP, NOT DOWN LIKE I WANT IT TO. Very unintuitive. Why did the opengl designers decide to do this?

Comment: Are you asking why OpenGL does it that way, or how you should work with the negation?

Comment: I'm asking why opengl does it that way...it really bugs me because it is not intuitive.

Comment: Are you sure that the up direction is where you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

the call is setting the POSITION of the light, therefore when it is directional it is taken to be the direction that the light is coming from.

take a look at the reply to: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/159448-why-the-last-element-of-light-position-means for further/more advanced explanation.